# Obtener los datos del empleado que esta registrando la asistencia

Tags: c#

Hola a todos de la comunidad, para aclarar la pregunta , lo que quiero hacer es: al ingresar el id de un empleado en una caja de textos, envió los siguientes datos a la tabla de asistencia: id del empleado, su nombre, la hora en que ha ingresado su id.
es un registro de asistencia.

```
  private void ValidarDNIExixteGA()
    {

        RNPersona nPersona = new RNPersona();
        string identifiction = bunifuCustomTextbox1.Text.Trim();

        if (nPersona.RN_VerifierIDEmployeeGA(identifiction) == true)
        {
            
          
          
          
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Le numero d'identification n'existe pas", 
            "Avertissement", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return;
           
        }
```

Comment: No entiendo tu problema.... estas guardando datos en la base de datos, y no sabes como leerlos?

Comment: A ver pa entendenterte, lo que tu quieres es dado el ID que guardas buscar los datos que te faltan?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y da más detalles

Comment: quiero obtener los datos del empleado al ingresar su id

Comment: Usas entityframework?

Comment: 2 cosas: 1. Bienvenido/a a SOes. 2. Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: no no uso entityframework

Comment: Tu edicion confunde mas todavia el problema. Cual es el problema? leer un registro de la base de datos? tu codigo no lee nada de la base de datos...

Comment: Exacto, persiste la confusión, antes era una cosa y ahora es otra, al final no se te acaba de entender

Comment: mira, estoy enviando datos a la base de datos, por eso es ese codigo, para enviar datos a una tabla que se llama asistencia. Ahora como quiero enviar esos datos?.  los quiero enviar introduciendo el id del empleado y ahora una vez introducido el id quiero traer todos los datos del empleado al que he introducido su id, y esos datos que he traído son los que envió a la tabla de asistencia. no se si me he explicado y si no resumiendo todo necesito saber cual es es codigo para registrar asistencia al introducir el id de un empleado. Gracias

Comment: Y los campos que tienen solo el igual y más nada, como los llenas?

Comment: los campos que tienen igual y mas nada son los que no llegue a obtener ese es mi problema

Comment: Chama pero seguimos en lo mismo, de donde salen esos campos, a ver, tu escribes el ID, con ese ID haces una consulta y obtienes el resto de los campos,  es eso lo que te hace falta?

Comment: si es lo que me hace falta

Comment: Oye haberlo dicho desde el principio, edita tu pregunta y pon la estructura de las tablas que te interesan pa ayudarte con la consulta

Comment: lo he conseguido hermano gracias por orientarme

Comment: Que bueno, ahora sería bueno también que subieras tu solución como respuesta por si a alguien más le hace falta

Comment: de acuerdo ahora lo subo

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void GuardarAssistenciaGA()
    {

        RNPersona persona = new RNPersona();
        RNAssistance rNassistance = new RNAssistance();
        EnAssistance enAssistance = new EnAssistance();
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        data = persona.BD_LeerPersonnaGA();

        data = persona.BD_LeerPersonnaGA();
        var heureentree = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");


        try
        {

            if (data.Rows.Count == 0) return;

            label_NombreRegistado.Visible = true;
            label_Identification.Visible = true;
            label_AvisoRegistro.Visible = true;
            label_NombreRegistado.Text = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[0]["nomprenom"]);
            label_Identification.Text = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[0]["id"]);
            label_AvisoRegistro.Text = " Enregistrement correct";

            enAssistance.idEmploye = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[0]["id"]);
            enAssistance.nomPrenomEmploye = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[0]["nomprenom"]);
           

            if (BDAssistance.Saved == true)
            {
                pictureBox_RegistroBueno.Visible = true;
                label_AvisoRegistro.Text = "Registro de asistencia correcto";

            }
```

Comment: Muy bien, pero la respuesta debes explicarla no es subir solo el codigo